# "JsonParseException: Unparseable date:" - Android error

Tags: java, android, rest, gson, retrofit

I am developing an android application which is being connected to the REST API, which I developed. I have developed the REST API using `Jersey` and `Hibernate`. In this API I have a method called, `findPatientById`. Below is its code....

**Rest Call
----**

```
   @GET
    @Path("/findPatientById/{idPatient}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Patient findPatientById(@PathParam("idPatient")int idPatient){

        PatientService patientService = new PatientService();
        Patient patient = patientService.findPatientById(idPatient);
        return patient;       
    }
```

**Database Layer
---**

```
public Patient findPatientById(int idPatient, Session session) {
        Patient patient = (Patient) session.get(Patient.class, idPatient);
        return patient;
    }
```

**Service Layer
----**

```
public Patient findPatientById(int idPatient) {
        Session session = patientDAOInterface.openCurrentSession();
        Transaction transaction = null;

        Patient patient = new Patient();
        try {
            transaction = patientDAOInterface.openTransaction(session);
            patient = patientDAOInterface.findPatientById(idPatient, session);
            System.out.println("DATE CREATED - "+patient.getDateCreated());
            transaction.commit();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.close();

            Language language = new Language();
            if (patient.getLanguage() != null) {
                Integer idlanguage = patient.getLanguage().getIdlanguage();
                language.setIdlanguage(idlanguage);
                patient.setLanguage(language);
            }

            if (patient.getDiabetesType() != null) {
                DiabetesType diabetesType = new DiabetesType();
                Integer iddiabetesType = patient.getDiabetesType().getIddiabetesType();
                diabetesType.setIddiabetesType(iddiabetesType);
                patient.setDiabetesType(diabetesType);
            }            

           // patient.setDateCreated(null);
          //  patient.setLastUpdated(null);
        }
        return patient;
    }
```

Below is the **Patient Bean**

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

    public class Patient implements java.io.Serializable {

        private Integer idpatient;
        private DiabetesType diabetesType;
        private Language language;
        private String customId;
        private String diabetesOther;
        private String firstName;
        private String lastName;
        private String email;
        private Date dob;
        private String parentEmail;
        private String gender;
        private Date diagnosedDate;
        private Double height;
        private Double weight;
        private String heightUnit;
        private String weightUnit;
        private String theme;
        private String userName;
        private String password;
        private Date dateCreated;
        private Date lastUpdated;

        public Patient() {
        }

        public Patient(DiabetesType diabetesType, Language language, String customId, String firstName, String email, Date dob, String gender, String theme, String userName, String password, Date lastUpdated) {
            this.diabetesType = diabetesType;
            this.language = language;
            this.customId = customId;
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.email = email;
            this.dob = dob;
            this.gender = gender;
            this.theme = theme;
            this.userName = userName;
            this.password = password;
            this.lastUpdated = lastUpdated;
        }

        public Patient(DiabetesType diabetesType, Language language, String customId, String diabetesOther, String firstName, String lastName, String email, Date dob, String parentEmail, String gender, Date diagnosedDate, Double height, Double weight, String heightUnit, String weightUnit, String theme, String userName, String password, Date dateCreated, Date lastUpdated) {
            this.diabetesType = diabetesType;
            this.language = language;
            this.customId = customId;
            this.diabetesOther = diabetesOther;
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
            this.email = email;
            this.dob = dob;
            this.parentEmail = parentEmail;
            this.gender = gender;
            this.diagnosedDate = diagnosedDate;
            this.height = height;
            this.weight = weight;
            this.heightUnit = heightUnit;
            this.weightUnit = weightUnit;
            this.theme = theme;
            this.userName = userName;
            this.password = password;
            this.dateCreated = dateCreated;
            this.lastUpdated = lastUpdated;
        }

        public Integer getIdpatient() {
            return this.idpatient;
        }

        public void setIdpatient(Integer idpatient) {
            this.idpatient = idpatient;
        }

        public DiabetesType getDiabetesType() {
            return this.diabetesType;
        }

        public void setDiabetesType(DiabetesType diabetesType) {
            this.diabetesType = diabetesType;
        }

        public Language getLanguage() {
            return this.language;
        }

        public void setLanguage(Language language) {
            this.language = language;
        }

        public String getCustomId() {
            return this.customId;
        }

        public void setCustomId(String customId) {
            this.customId = customId;
        }

        public String getDiabetesOther() {
            return this.diabetesOther;
        }

        public void setDiabetesOther(String diabetesOther) {
            this.diabetesOther = diabetesOther;
        }

        public String getFirstName() {
            return this.firstName;
        }

        public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return this.lastName;
        }

        public void setLastName(String lastName) {
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }

        public String getEmail() {
            return this.email;
        }

        public void setEmail(String email) {
            this.email = email;
        }

        public Date getDob() {
            return this.dob;
        }

        public void setDob(Date dob) {
            this.dob = dob;
        }

        public String getParentEmail() {
            return this.parentEmail;
        }

        public void setParentEmail(String parentEmail) {
            this.parentEmail = parentEmail;
        }

        public String getGender() {
            return this.gender;
        }

        public void setGender(String gender) {
            this.gender = gender;
        }

        public Date getDiagnosedDate() {
            return this.diagnosedDate;
        }

        public void setDiagnosedDate(Date diagnosedDate) {
            this.diagnosedDate = diagnosedDate;
        }

        public Double getHeight() {
            return this.height;
        }

        public void setHeight(Double height) {
            this.height = height;
        }

        public Double getWeight() {
            return this.weight;
        }

        public void setWeight(Double weight) {
            this.weight = weight;
        }

        public String getHeightUnit() {
            return this.heightUnit;
        }

        public void setHeightUnit(String heightUnit) {
            this.heightUnit = heightUnit;
        }

        public String getWeightUnit() {
            return this.weightUnit;
        }

        public void setWeightUnit(String weightUnit) {
            this.weightUnit = weightUnit;
        }

        public String getTheme() {
            return this.theme;
        }

        public void setTheme(String theme) {
            this.theme = theme;
        }

        public String getUserName() {
            return this.userName;
        }

        public void setUserName(String userName) {
            this.userName = userName;
        }

        public String getPassword() {
            return this.password;
        }

        public void setPassword(String password) {
            this.password = password;
        }

        public Date getDateCreated() {
            return this.dateCreated;
        }

        public void setDateCreated(Date dateCreated) {
            this.dateCreated = dateCreated;
        }

        public Date getLastUpdated() {
            return this.lastUpdated;
        }

        public void setLastUpdated(Date lastUpdated) {
            this.lastUpdated = lastUpdated;
        }

    }
```

Ok so when I call this REST method, I am getting the below `JSON` output.

```
{
  "idpatient": 86,
  "diabetesType": null,
  "language": null,
  "customId": "CUS790",
  "diabetesOther": null,
  "firstName": "Nirodha",
  "lastName": "Wije",
  "email": "ni00@gmail.com",
  "dob": "2005-10-16",
  "parentEmail": "niaasa500@gmail.com",
  "gender": "male",
  "diagnosedDate": "2016-11-16",
  "height": 0,
  "weight": 0,
  "heightUnit": null,
  "weightUnit": null,
  "theme": "Lite",
  "userName": "ranja",
  "password": "N1YL3+M0lnORHnKk0dPN8HYd1IBhWKAGO9Qsop7POgw=",
  "dateCreated": 1479311638000,
  "lastUpdated": 1479311638000
}
```

Now, I am connecting above method from my android application, I am using `Retrofit` for handling the REST API work. Below is the related android code...

```
private Patient restcallGetPatient(int idPatient){
    GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
    gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new DateTypeDeserializer());
    Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(RestCommon.URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .build();

    PatientEndPoint endPoint = retrofit.create(PatientEndPoint.class);
    Call<Patient> call = endPoint.findPatientById(idPatient);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Patient>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<Patient> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
            patients=response.body();

            Log.d("PROFILE_USER"," PATIENT_DETAILS "+patients.getFirstName());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("PROFILE_USER"," PATIENT_ERROR "+t.getMessage());
        }
    });

    return patients;
}
```

I am using a specific GSON Converter to convert `Date` and `TimeStamp` objects I am getting from the REST call. I have used it in the above `Retrofit` code. It is below.

```
public class DateTypeDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Date> {
    private  String[] DATE_FORMATS = new String[]{
            "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ",
            "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss",
            "yyyy-MM-dd",
            "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy",
            "HH:mm:ss",
            "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss aaa",
            "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS",
            "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSS",
            "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSS'Z'",
            "MMM d',' yyyy H:mm:ss a"
    };

    @Override
    public Date deserialize(JsonElement jsonElement, Type typeOF, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        for (String format : DATE_FORMATS) {
            try {
                return new SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.US).parse(jsonElement.getAsString());
            } catch (ParseException e) {
            }
        }
        throw new JsonParseException("Unparseable date: \"" + jsonElement.getAsString()
                + "\". Supported formats: \n" + Arrays.toString(DATE_FORMATS));
    }
}
```

Now, when I execute this android code, I am getting the below exception.

```
11-16 17:37:42.033 6534-6534/xxx.com.au.xyz W/System.err: com.google.gson.JsonParseException: Unparseable date: "1479317839000". Supported formats: 
11-16 17:37:42.033 6534-6534/xxx.com.au.xyz W/System.err: [yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ, yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss, yyyy-MM-dd, EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy, HH:mm:ss, MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss aaa, yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS, yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSS, yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSS'Z', MMM d',' yyyy H:mm:ss a]
11-16 17:37:42.033 6534-6534/xxx.com.au.xyz W/System.err:     at xxx.com.au.xyz.activities.ProfileUserActivity$DateTypeDeserializer.deserialize(ProfileUserActivity.java:474)
11-16 17:37:42.033 6534-6534/xxx.com.au.xyz W/System.err:     at xxx.com.au.xyz.activities.ProfileUserActivity$DateTypeDeserializer.deserialize(ProfileUserActivity.java:451)
11-16 17:37:42.033 6534-6534/xxx.com.au.xyz W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.TreeTypeAdapter.read(TreeTypeAdapter.java:58)
11-16 17:37:42.033 6534-6534/xxx.com.au.xyz W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:103)
11-16 17:37:42.033 6534-6534/xxx.com.au.xyz W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:196)
11-16 17:37:42.033 6534-6534/xxx.com.au.xyz W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:810)
11-16 17:37:42.033 6534-6534/xxx.com.au.xyz W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:775)
11-16 17:37:42.033 6534-6534/xxx.com.au.xyz W/System.err:     at retrofit.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:36)
11-16 17:37:42.033 6534-6534/xxx.com.au.xyz W/System.err:     at retrofit.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:24)
11-16 17:37:42.033 6534-6534/xxx.com.au.xyz W/System.err:     at retrofit.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java:148)
11-16 17:37:42.033 6534-6534/xxx.com.au.xyz W/System.err:     at retrofit.OkHttpCall.access$100(OkHttpCall.java:29)
11-16 17:37:42.033 6534-6534/xxx.com.au.xyz W/System.err:     at retrofit.OkHttpCall$1.onResponse(OkHttpCall.java:94)
11-16 17:37:42.033 6534-6534/xxx.com.au.xyz W/System.err:     at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$AsyncCall.execute(Call.java:168)
11-16 17:37:42.033 6534-6534/xxx.com.au.xyz W/System.err:     at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:33)
11-16 17:37:42.033 6534-6534/xxx.com.au.xyz W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
11-16 17:37:42.043 6534-6534/xxx.com.au.xyz W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
11-16 17:37:42.043 6534-6534/xxx.com.au.xyz W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
11-16 17:37:42.043 6534-6534/xxx.com.au.xyz D/PROFILE_USER:  PATIENT_ERROR Unparseable date: "1479317839000". Supported formats: 
                                                                        [yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ, yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss, yyyy-MM-dd, EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy, HH:mm:ss, MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss aaa, yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS, yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSS, yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSS'Z', MMM d',' yyyy H:mm:ss a]
11-16 17:37:42.053 6534-6534/xxx.com.au.xyz I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@b3857a0 time:13147437
```

OK now there is very important things to note. They are below.

1. The `lastUpdated` and `dateCreated` in `Patient` bean are `Timestamp` in database. In NetBeans I did auto POJO generation for `Hibernate` and they were created as `java.util.Date` in beans. The `dob` is a `Date` object in both database and bean.
2. I am using Mysql database.

So, due to the above exception, it is impossible for me to retrieve the bean from the database using a REST call in android app. I am pretty sure this is due to 2 different `date` formats the rest call returns, but that should be handled and that's why I applied the custom `GSON` converter. But no use, I am getting the same exception. I looked into number of solutions which suggests custom GSON converters built in various ways and still no good.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to convert JSON value to Long and return `new Date(valueAsLong)` after all date formats fail in method `deserialize()`:

In place of

```
throw new JsonParseException("Unparseable date: \"" + jsonElement.getAsString()
            + "\". Supported formats: \n" + Arrays.toString(DATE_FORMATS));
```

write

```
try {
    return new Date(jsonElement.getAsLong());
} catch (ClassCastException e) {
    throw new JsonParseException("Unparseable date: \"" + jsonElement.getAsString()
            + "\". Supported formats: \n" + Arrays.toString(DATE_FORMATS));
}
```

But I think the problem is on the server side. It should not return dates as milliseconds.

Comment: Timestamps are returned in Milliseconds

Comment: Anyway, can you give me a code example about how to do what you suggested in my Android code?

Comment: @PeakGen I added an example

Answer (score 0):

Try making an actual date to put into your Date formatter:

```
Timestamp stamp = new Timestamp(jsonElement.getAsString());
      Date date = new Date(stamp.getTime());
```

Then use `date` in this line:

```
return new SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.US).parse(date);
```

Comment: In where should I put this?